# Cannot install libswscale-ffmpeg3

Tags: opencv, raspbian, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to install opencv 2.4.13 on my rpi3. During this process, libswscale-ffmpeg3  needs to be installed. However, rpi3 returns with this error:

```
E: Unable to locate package libswscale-ffmpeg3
```

Any ideas on how to fix this error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: libavutil-ffmpeg54, ffmpeg, libv4l and libtbb-dev is also not installing